# Nested objects in Firestore have inconsistent field names

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update a nested object/map but I'm getting inconsistent results with dot notation.

This produces: a single field called `count.items` rather than the expected  map of `count`, with a sub-map of `items`:

```
var updateCategory = {}
updateCategory['count.items'] = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
batch.set(categoryRef, updateCategory, {merge: true});
```

This works for decrementing (in a totally separate function):

```
var updateItem = {}
updateItem['count.items'] = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)
var catRef = db.collection('categories').doc(category)
batch.update(catRef, updateItem, {merge: true})
```

FWIW, I've also tried:

```
var updateCategory = {
    count: {
        items: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try batch.update instead of batch.set?

Comment: That did it! Thank you!!